# How to combine the features extracted from different CNN architectures?

Tags: python, feature-extraction, transfer-learning

I have two CNN models, and I trained both of the models. The task is to extract the feature vectors from both models and combine them. How should we proceed?
CNN 1:

```
model1=Sequential()
#adding convolution layer
model1.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
#adding pooling layer
model1.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
#adding fully connected layer
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
#adding output layer
model1.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
#compiling the model
model1.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
#fitting the model
model1.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10)
```

CNN 2:

```
model2=Sequential()
#adding convolution layer
model2.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
#adding pooling layer
model2.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
#adding fully connected layer
model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
#adding output layer
model2.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
#compiling the model
model2.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
#fitting the model
model2.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10)
```

Comment: Hello Shereyas, could you please provide more information about your models?
For example the piece of code you declare the two models you want to join, what framework are you using such as tensorflow, keras, pytorch, theano or doing it in plain numpy (hope not the last one hahaha). Each programming language or library will have a small trick to join it, you will basically run a model that apply the feature extraction of those CNNs and then concatenate the feature vectors by flattening them

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte Sorry for not providing this information. I will be using Keras  with Python. The things is I have written code to classify images before, but I have always used a single architecture. I wanted to know how to combine features extracted from different CNN architectures before passing them to the fully connected layer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can [tf.keras.layers.concatenate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate) your extracted feature before flatten them in order to pass it to your fully connected layer. Note than you can actually use other operation such as multiply or add to merge your feature.